# Zend Framework 2 Form With Password

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db-table

I'm using zend framework 2, how can I force the user has set a password of 8 characters min, but both letters and numbers?
This is my code:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'password',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'        => 'password',
            'id'          => 'password',
            'class'       => 'span12 noradius',
            'placeholder' => 'Password'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password :'
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a custom validator, check this out: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html

```
class MyValid\PasswordStrength extends Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator
{
    const LENGTH = 'length';
    const UPPER  = 'upper';
    const LOWER  = 'lower';
    const DIGIT  = 'digit';

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::LENGTH => "'%value%' must be at least 8 characters in length",
        self::UPPER  => "'%value%' must contain at least one uppercase letter",
        self::LOWER  => "'%value%' must contain at least one lowercase letter",
        self::DIGIT  => "'%value%' must contain at least one digit character"
    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);

        $isValid = true;

        if (strlen($value) < 8) {
            $this->error(self::LENGTH);
            $isValid = false;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $value)) {
            $this->error(self::UPPER);
            $isValid = false;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $value)) {
            $this->error(self::LOWER);
            $isValid = false;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/\d/', $value)) {
            $this->error(self::DIGIT);
            $isValid = false;
        }

        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

You then select the custom validator:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'password',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            // What ever your namespace is etc determines this..
            'name'    => 'My\Validator\PasswordStrength',
        ),
    ),
)));
```